# I am converting HTML2WORD document using APACHE POI Java , but not able to add Header and Footer to newly generated word document

Tags: java, css, apache-poi

When am converting HTML 2 Word using POI am able to generate a new .doc with all styles and formatting used in html, but problem is not able to append header and footer in newly created .doc document. Does POI not support @page style of CSS? Also how to add header and footer to newly generated .doc document.

Below Code:

```
public void convertHtmltoWord(String html, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {  

    POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem();
    DirectoryEntry directory = poifs.getRoot();

    try {
        directory.createDocument("WordDocument", getInputStream(html));
        poifs.writeFilesystem(outputStream);
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
        poifs.close();
    }
}

public static InputStream getInputStream(String inputData) {
    InputStream targetStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(inputData);
    return targetStream;
}
```

Note: Converted .doc will give only give BODY part of .doc not Header and Footer. Like Page number in footer is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing using your code is **not** `HTML` to `Word` conversion.

Your code only creates a `POIFSFileSystem` having one `DirectoryEntry` containing the `HTML`. `Microsoft Word` will interpret that `HTML` and show it in the document body but the file is **not** a really binary `*.doc` file.

You can see this when you change something after opening in `Word` and then save. It will be saved as `HTML` and a additional directory `[Filename]-Files` will be created. That is needed because `HTML` does not provide embedding by default. So this directory contains all elements which could not embedded. This are pictures for example but also additional `HTML` files containing header and/or footer text.

So using your approach it is not possible to add header or footer to the `HTML`. It only can put `HTML` into the document body. And it not even creates a real `MIcvrosoft Word` file but only a `HTML` file which gets foisted  to `Microsoft Word` because of its fake file name `*.doc`.

Comment: ok. But how can we achieve this. I have formatted html String body with Styling (a report). And i want to convert those content into .doc/docx with header and footer part. Is this achievable with any java api open source , if yes then how?

Comment: @Chanchal Sharma: Only by parsing the `HTML` into its elements and then creating the appropriate elements for a `Word` document. There are multiple `Java` libraries to parse `HTML` and to create `Word` documents. `JSoup` and `apache poi` for example. Maybe there are complete libraries already to convert `HTML` to `Word`. But `StackOverflow` does not support questions about looking for books and/or libraries.