# @page CSS Style not working for apache-poi : html2Word conversation

Tags: java, html, css, apache-poi

Am using custom CSS Style for html2word convertor for Apache POI . There @page style of CSS is not working.
CSS Style is part of html body which need to be converted to word document. Below CSS:

```
private String getStyle() {
    String trBlack = "#37383D";
    String head = "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>"
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">" + "span.bodytext {color:" + trBlack
            + ";font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:8pt;word-wrap: break-word;text-indent: 10%;}"
                            + " @page { @bottom-right { padding-right:20px;content: ' Page ' counter(page); }}"
            
            + "</style>" + "</head>";
    return head;
}

String htmlContent = "<html>" + getStyle() + "<body>"
            + this.createDDTableContents(orderId, orderPlaced, finalReport, clientMatter, subjectId) + "</body></html>";
```

Api Conversation method:

```
public void convertHtmltoWord(String html, OutputStream outputStream) throws CourtExpressException, IOException {                                                                                                                                                       // a
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    // object
    POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem();
    DirectoryEntry directory = poifs.getRoot();

    try {
        directory.createDocument("WordDocument", getInputStream(html));
        poifs.writeFilesystem(outputStream);
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
        poifs.close();
    }
}

public static InputStream getInputStream(String inputData) {
    
    InputStream targetStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(inputData);
    return targetStream;
}
```

How can we use @page style for .doc/docx?
Above code will generate a .doc with input String html content with all CSS styling except @page Style. So is there any way to include it in .doc.

Comment: @AxelRichter am using Apache POI for Html2Word conversation.

Comment: @AxelRichter it gives us a way to convert input String to word document. Following code is being used:

Comment: [link] (https://www.programmersought.com/article/7385199270/) was using this link for .doc convertor. with my custom CSS and some input HTML

Comment: @AxelRichter below code of CSS and HTML : String head = "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>"
    + "<style type=\"text/css\">" + "span.bodytext {color:" + trBlack
    + ";font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:8pt;word-wrap: break-word;text-indent: 10%;}" + "</style>" + "</head>";
  return head;

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709688/i-am-converting-html2word-document-using-apache-poi-java-but-not-able-to-add-h. That approach does **not** create a real `Microsoft Word` document. So it is limited to the features of `HTML` and to how `Word` interprets that `HTML` then. Not a usable approach to convert `HTML` to `Word` in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah Thanks!! But is there any approach available for this type of prblm. I have html formatted String input which i need to convert into .doc/docx  document with header and footer. How can we achieve this. I know HWPF/XWPF is for generating word document . How can i insert my html body content  to HWPF/XWPF.

Comment: Only by parsing the `HTML` into its elements and then creating the appropriate elements for a `Word` document. There are multiple `Java` libraries to parse `HTML` and to create `Word` documents. `JSoup` and `apache poi` for example. Maybe there are complete libraries already to convert `HTML` to `Word`. But `StackOverflow` does not support questions about looking for books and/or libraries.

Comment: Yeah i know JSOUP will parse the html content but my problem is how to keep the source formatting there. Do you have any code snippet for that. public static 
   Document html2text(String html) {
        return Jsoup.parse(html);
    }    How to keep the source formatting intact with JSOUP?

Comment: Much too broad for an answer here. This cannot be solved using "any code snippet". This will be a complex project. So either take the challenge to make it your own project. Or ask the internet about "java html to word", try what you will find and decide to use the library which best fits your requirements. But most of them will not be free, I am afraid.